# mvc4 ajax jQuery html5 form validation C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I show validation for html5 form loaded with ajax jQuery and the information is sent through ajax post to the server?  I have a error message showing when something goes wrong; it is just a general message.  But, I want to display when some information is inputted wrong or something else.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="cnt_us-frm" id="cnt_us-frm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Submit")">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="fname">First name*: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" tabindex="1" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="lname">Last name: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="tel-area">Telephone*: </label>
        </td>
        <td>(<input name="tel_area" type="tel" id="tel_area" tabindex="3" size="3" maxlength="3" required="required" />)
<input name="fir_thr_tel" type="tel" id="fir_thr_tel" tabindex="4" size="3" maxlength="3" required="required" />-
<input name="lst_fur_tel" type="tel" id="lst_four_tel" tabindex="5" size="4" maxlength="4" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="emil">Email*: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" placeholder="example@you.com" name="email" id="emil" tabindex="6" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td> <label for="resn" id="resne">Reason*: </label></td> <td>
    <textarea name="resn" id="resn" tabindex="7" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="buttons">
        <td>
            <input type="reset" id="resbnt" value="Reset" tabindex="8" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="subnt" value="Submit" tabindex="9" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $Overlay = $("<section></section>");
        $Overlay.prop("id", "overlay");
        $modle = $("<article> </article>");
        $modle.prop("id", "modle");
        $Overlay.prependTo("body");
        $modle.prependTo("#overlay");
        $html = "<article> Something went wrong in saving your information!  Please check the require fields, sorry. </article> <button id='closeBtn' value='close' onclick='$.close();'> Close </button>"
        function center() {
            $("#modle").css('top', (($(window).height() - $modle.outerHeight()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
            $modle.css('left', (($(window).width() - $modle.outerWidth()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
        }

        $.open = function (value) {
            $("#overlay").show(); // show the modal
            $("#modle").html(value);
            center();
        }

        $.close = function () {
            $("#overlay").hide();
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        function messager(url) {
            $.post(url, $('form[name="cnt_us-frm"]').serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data.Success === true) {
                    $.get("/Home/PartialSubmit", function (data) {
                        $('#min-content').html(data)
                    });   // loads the page into 'min-content' section when document is ready/load 
                    $.close();
                }
                else {
                    $modle.hide('6500').html($html).show('2500');
                }
            })
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#subnt").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = "/Home/Submit";
                $.open("<h1> Sending... </h1>");
                messager(url);
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

and the server code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Submit(customers cust)
    {
            bool success = false;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                cust.tele_comp();
                saveIntoDb(cust); // database
                SendMail(cust); // mail sender
                success = true;
            }
            return Json(new { Success = success });
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = success });
        }
    }
```

and the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace img_site.Models
{
    public class customers
    {
        public string cust_id { get; set; } // from the database
        [Required]
        public string fname { get; set; }

        public string lname { get; set; }
        [Required][StringLength(3)]
        public string tel_area { get; set; }
        [Required][StringLength(3)]
        public string fir_thr_tel { get; set; }
        [Required][StringLength(3)]
        public string lst_fur_tel { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string resn { get; set; }
        public string tele { get; set; }
        public Boolean info = false, regex;

        public void tele_comp(){
            tele = "(" + tel_area + ")" + fir_thr_tel + "-" + lst_fur_tel;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you add data annotations on your model, and use `@Ajax.BeginForm` to post your form, the form will be validated by the mvc itself, in this case you are sending ajax call also explictly and you have to do validation as well explicitly.

So i recommend you to use mvc own `@Ajax.BeginForm` which will automatically post you form via ajax and will validate the model according to the data annotation you provide on model.

Comment: can you point me to an example or send me an example? I did try to use the mvc method for the form but, the form did not render on the page.

Thanks